# Nape physics. How to listen to SLEEP event of the space/world?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe, nape

How should I set a single callback which would trigger when there is no motion in the Space of Nape,  when each body "goes to sleep"?
I couldn't find any proper solution for this, but I guess this is a must-have for a physics engine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check `space.liveBodies.length` on tick (wherever you're calling `space.step()`).

When it reaches `0`, then all bodies are sleeping.

Comment: This is excactly what I was looking for! Thank you!